# Why find is giving inaccurate responses for 1M and 1G size?

Tags: linux, unix, find, ls, size

Why find is giving inaccurate/weird responses when I try to look for files that are 1 megabyte size or 1 gigabyte size ? Or even less than 1 megabyte or 1 gigabyte.

```
[root@server1 ~]# ls -lh
total 7.8M
-rw-------. 1 root root 1.7K Jan 24 00:15 anaconda-ks.cfg
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 4.8M Mar 15 16:09 backup.tar
-rwxrw--w-. 1 root root    0 Mar 23 18:15 file
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 9.6K Mar 11 19:26 grub.cfg
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root   88 Mar 17 20:10 local.repo
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root  512 Mar 14 22:33 mbr2.img
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root  512 Mar 14 22:30 mbr.img
-rwxr--r--. 1 root root  414 Mar 14 23:14 partition2.sh
-rwxr--r--. 1 root root  409 Mar 15 00:57 partition3.sh
-rwxr--r--. 1 root root  282 Mar 14 23:50 partition4.sh
-rwxr--r--. 1 root root 1.2K Mar 15 12:20 partition.sh
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 1.2K Mar 23 03:03 testfile
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 3.0M Apr  8  2020 zsh-5.0.2-34.el7_8.2.src.rpm
[root@server1 ~]#
[root@server1 ~]# find /root/ -size 1M |grep -v "/\."
/root/
/root/partition2.sh
/root/anaconda-ks.cfg
/root/partition.sh
/root/partition4.sh
/root/local.repo
/root/partition3.sh
/root/mbr.img
/root/testfile
/root/grub.cfg
/root/mbr2.img
[root@server1 ~]#
[root@server1 ~]# find /root/ -size 1G |grep -v "/\."
/root/
/root/partition2.sh
/root/anaconda-ks.cfg
/root/backup.tar
/root/partition.sh
/root/partition4.sh
/root/local.repo
/root/partition3.sh
/root/mbr.img
/root/testfile
/root/grub.cfg
/root/zsh-5.0.2-34.el7_8.2.src.rpm
/root/mbr2.img
[root@server1 ~]#
[root@server1 ~]# find /root/ -size -1M 
/root/file
[root@server1 ~]# find /root/ -size -1G 
/root/file
[root@server1 ~]#
```

I excluded hidden files with grep.

Answer (score 2):

The file size is **rounded up** to the nearest unit you specified, i.e. to the nearest 1M or 1G unit in your example.

Citing the documentation for `find`'s test option `-size` in https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/find.1.html

> ```
>    -size n[cwbkMG]
>           File uses less than, more than or exactly n units of
>           space, rounding up.  The following suffixes can be used:
> ```

[...]

> ```
>           The + and - prefixes signify greater than and less than,
>           as usual; i.e., an exact size of n units does not match.
>           Bear in mind that the size is rounded up to the next unit.
>           Therefore -size -1M is not equivalent to -size -1048576c.
>           The former only matches empty files, the latter matches
>           files from 0 to 1,048,575 bytes.
> ```

Comment: Thanks but how is 1G the nearest unit for 512 bytes files or 1k files ? I don't understand

Comment: @linuxuser "Rounded *up* to the nearest unit" – If the unit is `G` then even 1-byte file rounds up to 1G.

Comment: Thanks but weird, it just make no sens